# Canonical embedding vs. plaintext slots in Ring-LWE

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

I'm working on the *canonical embedding* mentioned in
[[LPR10]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230.pdf) and [[LPR13]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/293.pdf). What confuses me is that the difference and the relationship between the canonical embedding and the concept of ''plaintext slot'' in other works (e.g., [[SV11]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/133.pdf)).

Let's focus on the $m$-th cyclotomic number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ where $\zeta_m$ is an abstract element of order $m = 2^k$ for some $k$. For canonical embedding $\sigma$, it is comprised of $\left| \mathbb{Z}_m^* \right| = \varphi(m)$ embeddings $\sigma_i: K \mapsto \mathbb{C}$. More precisely, $\sigma_i(\zeta_m) = \omega_m^i$ and $\sigma(a) = (\sigma_i(a))_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*}$ for the primitive $m$-th root of unity $\omega_m$ and $a \in K$. The canonical embedding maps an element in $K$ to the vector space $H$ which is defined to be
\begin{gather}
H = \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}_m^*}: x_i = \overline{x_{m-i}},\ \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^* \}.
\end{gather}
Notice that $x_i = \overline{x_{m-i}}$ holds for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$. So using canonical embedding, it seems that there are only $\varphi(m)/2$ instead of $\varphi(m)$ ''slots'' for an vector in $H$ to encode complex numbers. If we want to encode a vector $\mathbf{v}$ of real numbers into an element in $K$ via $\sigma^{-1}$, is it true that the number of elements in $\mathbf{v}$ should be at most $\varphi(m)/2$ instead of $\varphi(m)$? (**Question 1**)

To generate plaintext slots, we can apply Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) to the polynomial ring $R_p = \mathbb{Z}_p[X]/\Phi_m(X)$ for the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(X)$. Note that $\Phi_m(X) = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*} (X - \zeta_m^i) \mod p$ where $(\zeta_m)^m \equiv 1 \mod p$ and CRT will result in $\varphi(m)$ slots for component-wise addition and multiplication. This CRT is indeed a kind of number-theoretic transform (NTT) by evaluating some polynomial $b \in R_p$ at $b(\zeta_m^i)$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$, which is quite similar to the situation where the embedding $\sigma_i$ is applied to $\mathcal{O}_K$, the ring of integers of $K$. Why do we have $\varphi(m)$ slots here while there are only $\varphi(m)/2$ ''slots'' in canonical embedding? (**Question 2**)

Many thanks

---

My understanding (updated on 29/07/19)

It seems that the difference between canonical embedding and plaintext slot comes from the difference between $\omega_m$ and $\zeta_m$, in which $\omega_m^m = 1 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\zeta_m^m = 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. For some $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$, we have
\begin{gather}
\sigma_i(a) = a(\omega_m^i) = a(\overline{\omega_m^{m-i}}) = \overline{a(\omega_m^{m-i})} \in \mathbb{C},
\end{gather}
in which the last equality is derived from the property of complex conjugate. The last equality implies that once one half of the $\sigma_i(a)$'s are fixed, the rest of them will be fixed as complex conjugate, which results in the factor $1/2$. However, note that there is no counterpart of this property of complex conjugate in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. That is, for some $b \in R_p$, 
\begin{gather}
b(\zeta_m^i) = b((\zeta_m^{m-i})^{-1}) \neq (b(\zeta_m^{m-i}))^{-1} \mod p.
\end{gather}
So it is safe to encode different values to the $\varphi(m)$ slots and there must exist a coresponding polynomial in $R_p$ using NTT.

Am I right?

Comment: While this isn't a full answer, one thing to note is that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is a dimension $\varphi(m)$ field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$,  but $H$ is a dimension $\varphi(m)/2$ field over $\mathbb{C}$. Using $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, you get that $H$ is actually a $\varphi(m)$ field over $\mathbb{R}$. This is a way of looking at things to get the dimensions to match up, although $\mathbb{Q}$ being countable and $\mathbb{R}$ being uncountable is an obstacle to this being the full argument.

Comment: Of course since the embedding isn't a bijection, there's no need for them to have the same cardinality. Still, computing $\sigma^{-1}$ would require having some good description of its domain, which is left out of the above argument.

Comment: To encode a vector of reals, one may abandon the imaginary part of each entry in $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{Z}_m^*}$. This will result in one half of the vector is identical to the other half. The inverse mapping $\sigma^{-1}$ is similar to fast fourier transform (FFT), I think.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for your helpful comments. It takes me a day to think about the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$. Of course we have such unitary matrix B (c.f., Section 2.2 in [LPR13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/293.pdf) ) that contributes to the isomorphism $H \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{\varphi(m)}$. However, it seems that the conponent-wise addtion and multipilication in $H$ cannot be transfromed into $\mathbb{R}^{\varphi(m)}$ using B. So, although we have dimensions match up, we still have $\varphi(m)/2$ space in $H$ to encode reals.

Comment: I think you're assuming that if we want to encode an element with real coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ (so $\varphi(m)$ coefficients), we can do it by encoding an element with real coefficients in $H$ (so $\varphi(m)/2$ *real* coefficients). This isn't the case, because $\sigma$ doesn't map real numbers to real numbers (note that specifically $\sigma(1) = \zeta_m$ is complex). In general, you're asking about the "canonical" or "minkowski" embedding, of which there are non-cryptographic resources you can consult. It might be useful for you to try some explicit computations with a CAS.

Comment: [Sage supports computations in number fields](https://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~sorger/chow/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field.html), including those involving the embedding you're interested in.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for the link. It is really helpful to me.

Comment: A clear explaination can be found in Section 2.1 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1043.pdf)